# clone sharepoint enviroments?

Tags: asp.net

We are under process of clone on QA environments to new environments. machines and urls will changes. How we can configure these changes in central admin level in new environment?

Please advice me.

Comment: which sharepoint version?

Comment: SharePoint 2007 and MOSS SP1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend going about it differently. You can put all your customizations into a SharePoint Solution in Visual Studio, setup a separate brand new SharePoint Server, then Deploy all your Customizations to the new Environment using WSP Installer / Deployment. If you try to clone an existing environment you will spend a lot of unnecessary time trying to reconfigure the old environment to work on the new Server, and it will be an ongoing recurring headache to try and keep them in sync that way.

If you setup your solution correctly, you should be able to include all your changes that way easily, which will then allow you to install updates to the second environment with one Power Shell Command and you are done!

Answer (score 1):

Short of buying a 3-rd party tool, your best bet is to do a backup-and-restore into the new environment. It's not easy to keep them in sync after that, so you'll want to develop and enforce some kind of workflow that requires the new stuff going through your qa env.  Here's a great article about using CA for backup-and-restore in various scenarios>

http://blah.winsmarts.com/2007-10-Backup_and_Restore_Strategies_in_MOSS_2007.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I maintain pre-production and development environments that are as close to a mirror of production as possible.  With this setup, I use one forest per pre-production environment in order to be able to reuse hostnames for Web Applications.

http://sharepoint.nauplius.net/p/sharepoint-test-environments.html